# Using imported interceptor on controller not working in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I like to organise my project along feature lines with different modules for cross cutting concerns eg: configuration, authentication, etc. However when importing an `Interceptor` into a feature module for use with a `Controller` Nest doesn't seem to reuse the existing instance.

**`controllers.module.ts`**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    // ConfigService is exported from this module.
    ConfigModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // For debugging purposes I used a factory so I could place a breakpoint and see
    // when the Interceptor is being created.
    {
      provide: MyInterceptor,
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => new MyInterceptor(config),
      inject: [
        ConfigService
      ]
    }
  ],
  exports: [
    MyInterceptor
  ]
})
export class ControllersModule {

}
```

**`customer.module.ts`**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ControllersModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    CustomerController
  ],
  providers: [
    CustomerService
  ]
})
export class CustomerModule {

}
```

**`customer.controller.ts`**

```js
@Controller("/customers")
@UseInterceptors(MyInterceptor)
export class CustomerController {
  constructor(private readonly customerService: CustomerService) {

  }

  @Get()
  customers() {
    return this.customerService.findAll();
  }
}
```

When the application starts up, I can see the `MyInterceptor` provider factory being called, with an instance of `ConfigService`. However then I see the following error on the console

```
error: [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyInterceptor (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the CustomerModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current CustomerModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CustomerModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
```

Now maybe there's something about how Nest instantiates/uses Interceptors that I'm not understanding but I thought that given that `MyInteceptor` had been created, and the `ControllersModule` imported by `CustomerModule` that the bean would have been available and applied to `CustomerController`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interceptors (along with other request lifecycle classes) are kinda like `pseudoproviders` in that that are `@Injectable()` but they aren't added to a `providers` array for binding. You can [bind then via the providers array](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors), (`APP_INTERCEPTOR`) but that will cause it to be bound globally.

Because interceptors can't be added to a `providers` array the way you are trying, you need to instead add the `ConfigModule` to whatever module uses the interceptor.

Comment: Yeah I think it relates to https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3856#issuecomment-575917099 (another `pseuso-provider`)

Answer (score 1):

and as a side-note, **you shouldn't use `@Res` with interceptors in nestjs**

#### why

look, when you are using an interceptor, you are handling (with using `.handle()`) the stream of response (`observable`) not a whole package of it, **but** using express `@Res` actually is somehow getting around the whole flow of response streaming.

this is also explicitly mentioned in [nestjs official documents](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#response-mapping):

> We already know that handle() returns an Observable. The stream
> contains the value returned from the route handler, and thus we can
> easily mutate it using RxJS's map() operator.
>
> WARNING
>
> The response mapping feature doesn't work with the
> library-specific response strategy (using the @Res() object directly
> is forbidden).